# How to make SQL Server use the Olson time zones instead of Windows ones by default

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timezone, azure-sql-managed-instance

I'm trying to make my SQL Server use the Olson time zones instead of the Windows ones.

The web doesn't really give an answer on how to do it and make it system wide.

I don't know if that's possible to make it the default, and how to do it, or if I just should move to a different database provider but since my current infrastructure uses SQL Server I'd like to know if it is possible nonetheless.

If it's possible, I'd like to know how to do it locally but also when I'll be migrating it to an Azure SQL Server instance.

Comment: Make SQL use of time zones in what way? One place where I know that TZ names are used explicitly is in the `at time zone` construct which specifically takes Windows TZ names. Changing persistence layers over that one thing seems drastic, but chase your bliss. One alternative would be to find an Olson-to-Windows TZ translation file. I did a little searching and found [this](https://github.com/uddhav/tzid-from-geo/blob/master/olson_to_windows.json) which you could probably stick into a table in your database as static lookup data.

Comment: @BenThul - That file is super old.  Best to use the [CLDR mappings](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).  Or a library in the application layer such as [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter).

Comment:  - use whatever file you want. My point is that if it's important to use the Olson TZ names in a regime where doing so is not available, use a translation of what you want to use to what you _can_ use. Your point does imply that doing so will require ongoing maintenance as different locales change how/when they do DST.

Comment: I guess my question is... why? How are the timezones provided by SQL Server insufficient for your purpose? SQL Server is using the timezone data provided by the host operating system, so if you think they're out of date then push your hosting provider to apply Windows updates.

Comment: I want to use the Olson time zones because I use APIs that return the Olson time zones and they don't match with the Windows time zones. So I could use a translator it seems but isn't it better to change it so that it only uses the Olson time by default instead of using a translator between the two just in case it would break ? Since relying on an extra library is never recommended if you can do without.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint how would I apply the CLDR mappings to the SQL Server configuration ?

Comment: Charlieface showed one way in his answer below.  That's a pure SQL approach.  The more common way is to do the conversion outside of SQL Server, such as in whatever application might be calling it.  That depends a lot on your usage though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a mapping table of Olson time zones to Windows time zones, and then use a function to convert.

For example

```sql
CREATE TABLE TzToWindows(Olson varchar(300) PRIMARY KEY, Windows varchar(50) NOT NULL);
```

Then create an inline Table Valued Function to query it

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AtOlsonTimeZone (@value datetimeoffset, @olson varchar(300))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
SELECT @value AT TIME ZONE tz.Windows AS value
FROM TzToWindows tz
WHERE tz.Olson = @olson;
```

You can then do a simple `SELECT`, or you can `CROSS APPLY` it from another table.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.AtOlsonTimeZone(SYSDATETIME(), 'Pacific/Fakaofo');
```

[**This fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/sC2stLri) has data that has been pulled from [the official Unicode Github repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unicode-org/cldr/main/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).

Comment: I see, in my case I'd need the function to receive the Olson time zone as a parameter and then make SQL Server use the windows equivalent to calculate the offset I think. But thank you for the answer it's what I was looking for. The only question is, by declaring the xml, does that affect the system which will now recognize an Olson time zone to its equivalent in windows ? Is it the same as entering `INSERT () VALUE ()` for each time zone ?

Comment: That is what this function does. The XML is just used for a one-off parse and insert into the table. Yes it's equivalent to any other batch insert.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't understand the use of the `datetimeoffset` then. Could you explain its use ?

Comment: You pass the function an existing `datetimeoffset` value, for example the result of `SYSDATETIME()` or a value from a variable or column, and an Olson time zone, and the result is the converted time using `AT TIME ZONE` by looking up the TZ from the table. You can also use `datetime` or `datetime2`, but then all it will do is add an offset without adjusting the actual local time. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I see, but what if I only receive the Olson tz as data and don't know the offset ? Or should I just have UTC as a default parameter ?

Comment: @Jimmy - I think you're saying you have a `datetime` (or `datetime2`) variable that is in UTC that you want to convert to a specific time zone?  You can do `dbo.AtOlsonTimeZone(@yourdatetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', @thetimezone)`.

Comment: @Charlieface - The approach is solid, but the import functions in the fiddle need some work.  Specifically, the `type` field in the XML file can have more than one time zone, separated by spaces.  Additionally, to get _all_ Olson time zones, you also have to import the  [cldr/common/bcp47/timezone.xml](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/bcp47/timezone.xml).  Where there is more than one in the `alias` field, the first is the one that will be in `windowsZones.xml` and the others are aliases of that zone.

Comment: Updated fiddle with `STRING_SPLIT`. My intention anyway was to show the approach to querying not the loading of the data

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I meant that I will be receiving a place with an Olson time zone, and I need the sql script to translate that Olson tz to a Windows tz for further work in order for SQL Server not to be mistaken between the two, because in the end it needs to compare the place's open hours in its tz to show it as open or closed.

Comment: And also, should it return a `table` or should it return a `NVARCHAR` ?

Comment: It returns a table with a single `datetimeoffset` column. This is called an *inline Table Valued Function* and is much faster than a *Scalar Function*. You can put in a `FROM` or `APPLY`